# Как написать 3D лабиринт на OpenGL или на DirectX?

Tags: c, opengl, directx

Задали курсовую - написать 3D лабиринт.Необходимо обязательно использовать OpenGL или DirectX. Мой выбор больше склоняется к OpenGL (он вроде бы проще осваивается). С графикой никогда дел не имел и более  менее знаю только язык Си. Что посоветуете выбрать? Какую литературу для начинающих начать читать ? О С++ ничего не знаю  и в этой работе им пользоваться запрещено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала нужно определиться, какой конвеер фиксированный или с шейдерами. Фиксированный уже как с Doom3 перестали использовать, но позволяет быстро что-то сделать. Если ты хочешь развиваться, как программист выбирай второй путь и вот тебе ссылка на лучшее уроки в мире по OpenGL https://learnopengl.com/

Comment: Но там C++, я же могу только на Си

Comment: На чистом C писать нынче слишком хардово. Вместо потоков ввода вывода stdio юзай, а vector сам сделай просто динамический массив который сам переаллоцируется когда достиг своего предела

Comment: не нашел , как они делают движение персонажа(камеры)

Comment: Камера делается легко. Есть 4 известных мне способа. Введи для начала углы Эйлера думаю быстро разберешься

Comment: ,а там написано, как сделать стены осязаемыми ?

Comment: Ахаха. Там надо пилить на нахождение пересечение объектов. Можешь делать как на GPU так и на CPU

Comment: @Elvin, это обёртка на C++. Сам же OpenGL доступен на Си (ибо это просто огромный набор функций без классов и даже структур).